# Page for custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, pages, terms

I'm a newbie in WordPress and I've just created a new custom-taxonomy called categories under a custom post type called arts. Is there a way I can create a custom page to display the 'categories's custom type? Such that a user can navigate to arts/categories and see all the terms under the categories taxonomy.

Answer (score 1):

This is a default part of the custom taxonomy functionality built into WordPress. When you register your taxonomy, the following argument play a part in determining whether to display that archive and where:

- `public` (is it accessible on the front end?)
- `rewrite` (how do the permalinks work?)

You should [read through all of the arguments](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Parameters) *closely* to understand how they work.

You also need to make sure that your taxonomy name does not collide with any of the [reserved terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms).

Finally, there's already a 'Category' taxonomy, so you may be better off just adding that taxonomy (that is already on Posts) to your custom post type. You would do that in your `register_post_type()` function with the `taxonomies` argument like it's done [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-category-to-a-custom-post-type).